# Can the server owner disable cosmetic items?

Tags: team-fortress-2, server-administration

[Valve designed Team Fortress 2 classes with distinct silhouettes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ebvbVO1QE5o) to effectively convey visual information to the player. Hats and other cosmetic items can greatly hamper visibility and may change the profile of classes entirely.

[image: silhouettes]

The game is also under blame for increasing performance issues which certainly are partially caused by dozens or even hundreds of new 3D models the players carry in any given multiplayer match.

Because Valve's Source engine games generally give a lot of control for server owners, can even administrators disable these items on their own servers?

Comment: Do you want to force players to use only the initial set of weapons that were available at release, or only the items that can be placed into the cosmetic spots?

Comment: @zero298: The question is about cosmetic items (including weapon skins), not new weapons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using a server plugin like [whitelist.tf](https://whitelist.tf/). It allows server owners to disallow certain items on their server and has several presets depending on your needs.

Comment: I'm aware that weapons can be disabled, but is it possible to blacklist cosmetic items (and preferably all at once)?

Comment: @user176801 Did you look at the configuration section?  There is a toggle for "Hats" and "Miscs" as well as other fluff in the "Global Settings".

Comment: I missed "global settings". Apparently all cosmetic items are covered.

Comment: Can weapons skins be disabled? This isn't explicitly stated.